# Putting certain values at the bottom of sort in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table that counts the win percentage of players, looking like this:

```
name    games   score   percentage
name1   6       3       50
name2   10      8       80
name3   2       2       100
  ⋮
```

I want to sort it by percentages, but I want only players with, say, 5 or more games to appear and the rest be at the bottom, so for example the list above would become:

```
name    games   score   percentage
name2   10      8       80
name1   6       3       50
  ⋮
name3   2       2       100
  ⋮
```

Adding two levels to the sort doesn't work no matter which way I arrange it.

How can I do it?

Comment: you need to create a new column where you calculate whether you want it top or  bottom `=IF(B2>=5,"TOP","BOTTOM"). Now sort your data descending on the new column, then by percentage.

Comment: @MátéJuhász That's simple enough and works, Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a “helper column” — I’ll assume that Column E is available. 
Set `E2` to `=B2>=5` and drag down. 
This evaluates to `TRUE` in the rows that you want in the first group
and `FALSE` in the rows that you want in the second group.

[image]

Then sort on Column `E` (descending, so `TRUE` comes before `FALSE`)
and then whatever other criteria you want (e.g., Column `D` descending). 
You can hide Column `E` if you want.